# Can I edit a Word document on my Mac while the file is open on my Windows 10 Computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, macos, mac, microsoft-word

I share my primary drive (from my PC) over my network, and connect to it via my Mac. I am often working on the same document on both computers. I use my Mac when away from my desktop computer.

Is it safe to edit a document on my Mac while the document is still open on my PC? Does this risk data corruption? Will my PC automatically pick up the updates, or will I have to close and reopen the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The DOC and DOCX formats do not natively support multi user editing.

Having the file open in one application places a lock on the file and subsequent opens should see this lock and go into READ ONLY mode for the file.

Using a supported sharing system such as OneDrive or SharePoint you could set up multi user editing, but just reading from a basic network share will result in corruption and data loss if a file is opened and edited in two different applications and computers.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This answers my question perfectly.